# Invisible floor and ceil math delimiters

Tags: context, bigdelim

Why the floor and ceil math delimiters don't display?

Code:

```
\starttext
\startformula
    \Bigl\lfloor \frac{x}{y}\Bigr\rfloor
\stopformula
\startformula
    \Bigl\lceil \frac{x}{y}\Bigr\rceil
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It displays for me.

Comment: ...but not for me on TexLive 2014, mac os x, using `context` as the command to process the given input.

Comment: for me `\left\lfloor ... \right\rfloor` works ok.

Comment: Maybe you need additional fonts.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, too.

Comment: @Thruston: For me too, so \big, \bigl, \bigr and their variants should work too, but it is not the case.

Comment: @Sigur: No, \left and \right work so you do not need additional fonts. It is a bug of ConTeXt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug! It has been fixed in the beta `ver: 2015.5.11`.

If you are using ConTeXt standalone, you can update your distribution and these will work. The fix would also be part of TL2015.

In case you are wondering, why such this bug existed, ConTeXt has an experimental feature (motivated by MathML fences). For example, if you want the `\lfloor ... \rfloor` to appear in blue, you can use:

```
\setupmathfence[floor][color=blue]
\starttext
$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $
\stoptext
```

This only works with `\left..\right` and not `\big` etc. The above example gives

[image]

It is also possible to use this to define new fences (what LaTeX calls PairedDelimiters). For example,

```
\definemathfence [ABS][bar][ command=yes, color=blue]
```

defines a command `\ABS{...}` that is equivalent to `\fenced{bar}{...}`, which, in-turn, is equivalent to `\left| ... \right|`.

Some of the delimiters were missing and as a side-effect, `\big\lfloor` was not working.